# How to install imtools module for in Ubuntu

Tags: python

I am using python in Ubuntu, but when I import the `imtools` module:

```
import imtools
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named imtools
```

How can I install the module?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're possibly following:

> Jan Erik Solem's book "Programming Computer Vision with Python"

If that is the case then you are supposed to create the file imtools.py yourself.
You then store the functions you've made in that file so you can use them later on.